# How to use the command update-alternatives --config java

Tags: java, debian

I am installing Apache Solr on Linux Debian (Squeeze). I have been instructed to install sun-java jdk 1st. Then am told that I should use the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to make sure that a particular java (sun-java) is the default runtime. Yet when I run this command I get:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.4                           1044      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java       63        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

So which number should I select to have sun-java as the default runtime? 
Also, what exactly do th auto and manual modes mean? If I select 3 above and run the update-alternative command I receive the same output as above, again nothing seems to have changed except that the * is now in front of the 3, though it still reads manual mode.

Is there a way to confirm that what I have done is correct?

Comment: also you can ADD nonexistent alternative to an EXISTING link with --install /path/to/my_existing_program_link existing_alternative_name /bin/path/to/alternative/program [priority number, ie 100]  and then select it from the list with --config || this method is needed if the program didn't properly add itself as an alternative when it was installed. You might need to use sudo if you need permissions elevated (which is identified by permission errors during --install and --config)

Answer (score 74):

You will notice a big change when selecting options if you type in "java -version" after doing so.  So if you run `update-alternatives --config java` and select option `3`, you will be using the *Sun* implementation.
Also, with regards to `auto` vs `manual mode`, making a selection should take it out of `auto mode` per [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) stating:

> When using the `--config` option, alternatives will list all of the
>   choices for the link group of which given name is the master link. You
>   will then be prompted for which of the choices to use for the link
>   group. Once you make a change, the link group will no longer be in
>   `auto mode`. You will need to use the `--auto` option in order to return
>   to the automatic state.

And I believe `auto mode` is set when you install the first/only JRE/JDK.

Answer (score 70):

Assuming one has installed a JDK in `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_144` then:

1. Install the alternative for javac

   ```
   $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac 1
   ```
2. Check / update the alternatives config:

   ```
   $ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
   ```

If there is only a single alternative for `javac` you will get a message saying so, otherwise select the option for the new JDK.

To check everything is setup correctly then:

```
$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac

$ ls -l /usr/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Sep  4 17:10 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Sep  4 17:10 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac
```

And finally

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_144
```

Repeat for java, keytool, jar, etc as needed.

Comment: How do I update this automatically? I just get tired of having to manually configure it every time when calling `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

Comment: In the past I would just update one directory (say `/usr/java/latest`) to point to the java version I wanted to use, and put `/usr/java/latest/bin` on my path so I only needed to do one update to get javac, java, javap, etc (all in one change).

Answer (score 45):

`update-alternatives` is problematic in this case as it forces you to update all the elements depending on the JDK.

For this specific purpose, the package `java-common` contains a tool called `update-java-alternatives`.

It's straightforward to use it. First list the JDK installs available on your machine:

```
root@mylaptop:~# update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

And then pick one up:

```
root@mylaptop:~# update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Note: it will print "no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so" but it can be ignored since the commands get updated anyways.

Answer (score 28):

## This is how I install jdk

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/
sudo mkdir java
sudo tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/jdk-8u192-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo ln -s  jdk1.8.0_192 current
for file in /opt/java/current/bin/*
do
   if [ -x $file ]
   then
      filename=`basename $file`
      sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/$filename $filename $file 20000
      sudo update-alternatives --set $filename $file
      #echo $file $filename
   fi
done
```

Comment: Just one missing step: `cd /opt/java` before the tar command

Answer (score 14):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Most of the time, when I change my `java` version, I also want to use the same `javac` version.
I use `update-alternatives` this way, using a `java_home` alternative instead :

## Installation

**Install every java version in `/opt/java/<version>`, for example**

```
~$ ll /opt/java/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 jan. 22 21:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 feb.  7 13:40 ../
drwxr-xr-x  8 stephanecodes stephanecodes 4096 jan.   8  2019 jdk-11.0.2/
drwxr-xr-x  7 stephanecodes stephanecodes 4096 dec.  15  2018 jdk1.8.0_201/
```

**Configure alternatives**

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /opt/java/current java_home /opt/java/jdk-11.0.2/ 100
~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /opt/java/current java_home /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_201 200
```

**Declare `JAVA_HOME` (In this case, I use a global initialization script for this)**

```
~$ sudo sh -c 'echo export JAVA_HOME=\"/opt/java/current\" >> environment.sh'
```

Log Out or restart Ubuntu (this will reload `/etc/profile.d/environment.sh`)

## Usage

**Change java version**

Choose the version you want to use

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java_home

There are 2 choices for the alternative java_home (providing /opt/java/current).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/java/jdk-11.0.2     200       auto mode
  1            /opt/java/jdk-11.0.2     200       manual mode
* 2            /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_201   100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

**Check version**

```
~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

~$ javac -version
javac 11.0.2
```

**Tip**

Add the following line to `~/.bash_aliases` file :

```
alias change-java-version="sudo update-alternatives --config java_home && java -version && javac -version"
```

Now use the `change-java-version` command to change java version

Comment: Love this technique !  A couple of things missing from the description: You need to create `/opt/java` and you also need to add `/opt/java/current/bin` to your $PATH

Answer (score 9):

There are many other binaries that need to be linked so I think it's much better to try something like `sudo update-alternatives --all` and choosing the right alternatives for everything else besides `java` and `javac`.

Answer (score 9):

### After installing any open jdk simply run and select your desired jdk:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

[image: Command line screenshot]

Comment: This changes only java link, but in JDK there are many more tools like javac, javap, keytool, jpackage etc. Use update-java-alternatives script for this, that handles all tools in JDK. But as I see it, it's unnecessarily complicated – all the JDK command should be soft linked to another soft link, that actually points to real jdk, like javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/current-jvm/bin/javac and current-jvm -> /usr/lib/jv/java-11-xyz. This way it suffices to just change one link to change whole JDK.

Answer (score 8):

**Steps I followed to install java 17 in Debian 10**

Step 1:
Download jdk from URL and move to server
https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb

Alternatively you can download directly in server using weget command

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install wget curl
wget https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb
```

Step 2:
installed using command '

```bash
sudo apt install ./jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb
```

step 3:
Update default javac and java version as 17

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --config javac

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Step 4:
Check jre version

```bash
java -version
```

Check jdk version

```bash
javac -version
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to switch the jdk on a regular basis (or update to a new one once it is released), it's very convenient to use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/).

You can install additional tools like maven with sdkman, too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at
https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage
At the bottom of this page an other method is descibed using a command from the java-common package

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 versions of java Installed on my AWS EC2 instance; [java 8 & 11](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-11-openjdk-11-on-rhel-8/)
but couponservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file needs java 11 to run because this .jar file was created using java 11.

[root@ip-172-31-94-132 ~]# **alternatives --config java**

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

Selection    Command

- 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

- 2           /usr/java/jdk-11.0.12/bin/java

**Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number**: 2

[root@ip-172-31-94-132 ~]# **java -version**

java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)

Now you can run .jar file specific to

[root@ip-172-31-94-132 ~]# **java -jar couponservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Reference:- https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=jdk11&f=2