# Install Java7 on Ubuntu 16.04 through bash script

Tags: java, linux, bash, java-7, ubuntu-16.04

I have below function `java_install` written in a bash script to install `java` on Linux box, to which I pass `jdk-1.7.0_80-linux-x64.tgz` as `JAVA_PACKAGE`.
Now what is happening is java gets installed and works fine only within the script. Once I come out of this script, none of the java functionalities work, not even `java -version`. Could someone please help me on what I might be missing here? Basically, I just want java to be installed permanently on this box once this script is executed.

```
java_install() {
local JAVA_PACKAGE=$1
local TMPDIR=/tmp/quickstart
local TARGET=/usr/share
    if [ -n "$JAVA_PACKAGE" ] && [ -f "$JAVA_PACKAGE" ]; then
  rm -rf $TMPDIR
  mkdir -p $TMPDIR
  cp $JAVA_PACKAGE $TMPDIR
  ( cd $TMPDIR && tar fxz $JAVA_PACKAGE && rm $JAVA_PACKAGE )
  local JAVA_BASENAME=$(ls -1 $TMPDIR)
  mkdir -p $TARGET
  if [ -d "$TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME" ]; then
    echo "# Java already installed at $TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME"
    log_info "Java already installed at $TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME"
  else
    echo "# Java now installed at $TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME"
    log_info "Java now installed at $TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME"
    mv $TMPDIR/$JAVA_BASENAME $TARGET
  fi
  rm -rf $TMPDIR

  # now create a script to export these settings
  export JAVA_HOME=$TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
else
  echo "# cannot find java package to install"
  log_error "cannot find java package to install"
fi
}
```

Comment: After you exit the script, the JAVA_HOME and PATH are no longer in effect. Try setting them manually. Is there a reason why you are not using the (very commonly used) Java PPA (webupd8team)?

Comment: Define `none of the java functionalities work` - exes not found or something more sinister?

Comment: @John3136 Functonality like `java-keytool`

Comment: @RealSkeptic I need everything to be done through script and nothing manual.

Comment: I suggest to check content of `$JAVA_BASENAME` because of this `JAVA_BASENAME=$(ls -1 $TMPDIR)` and `export JAVA_HOME=$TARGET/$JAVA_BASENAME`.

Comment: @Elina That is not an answer. What does it do? "Command not found" or it finds it then causes your computer to burst into flames or something else?

Comment: @Cyrus both the values should be fine as JAVA is working fine within the script. I just need Java to work from everywhere, and not just within this script.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I already get a jdk bundled in a bin, and i need to use this same jdk.tgz file to install java.

Comment: @John3136 yes it gives command not found. And obviously does not burst into flames. Also, when i try `java -version`, it says java not installed.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Then your scripts needs to update the system's profile so that those environment variables are available to all users. It will still require log out and log-in again. A script cannot set environment variables for its calling process or any other non-child process.

Answer (score 0):

Use `update alternatives` within your script to make your java installation available:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "path to you java executable" 1
```

More information on this topic can be found here: [How to use the command update-alternatives --config java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java).
Alternatively you can write the export commands for `JAVA HOME` and `PATH` to your `.bashrc` from within your script (if using bash). This way the modified variables are available in the bash shell.