# invalid flag: -jar after upgrading java package to 1.8.0_211

Tags: java, jar, javac, executable-jar

We upgraded java package to 1.8.0_211. After upgrading, I was restarting my java services, which were running before , to reflect the upgraded changes.

But while running the `.jar` file, I am getting following error

```
javac: invalid flag: -jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Below is the command I am using to run it.

```
 nohup java -jar master-f41ba7c-true_26-04-2019_17.55.08.jar --spring.config.location=file:properties/application.properties &
```

**Edit 1**
when I checked the version of java on my newly upgraded java server it shows with javac

```
$ java -version

javac version 1.8.0_211
```

But when I use the same command to check the version of java on my old java server. It shows like this :

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
```

In the new it prints `javac` instead of java

How can I make my jar run as before.

Comment: `javac` is a compiler. why do you want to run your jar with it?

Comment: @mangusta I am not using javac command to run , But still I am getting that error. Please check my edits, I have updated the command also

Comment: The command seems to be saying you're using javac, so you probably are. Maybe you accidentally aliased java to javac? What does `which java` print?

Comment: @yshavit Where do we alias ?? Also , when I checked the version of java it shows with javac . Please check my edit 1

Comment: Is this on Linux, Mac, Windows? If Linux or Mac, what does `which java` print?

Comment: @yshavit It's linux machine

Comment: `alias java` would tell you if you have an alias. Otherwise it's in the `alternative` commands...

Comment: @Matthieu -bash: alias: java: not found

Comment: Then check `update-alternative` command. You probably have `java` pointing to `javac`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java

Comment: @Matthieu Thanx , It was same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something probably messed the Java alternatives. Try:

```
sudo update-alternative --config java
```

and check the version you're using is *not* pointing at `javac` command. It can be a copy-paste error from the installation script where `java` and `javac` were mixed.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java) for more details about the command.