# OpenJDK and update-alternatives command

Tags: java, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I've done:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-{8,11,14}-{jdk,source,doc}
```

Now I often use the commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc
```

...and maybe a few others, but when I type this command:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/*j*
```

I still find many Java-related commands which have not been affected by the above sequence of update-alternatives commands.

What is the full list of update-alternatives commands that will change every single Java-related command to a specified Java version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this can be a problem for many software, this is a specific problem for Java on Ubuntu. Fortunately there is a specific solution, a program, call:

```
update-java-alternatives
```

I have just use it the following way:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.14.0-openjdk-amd64
```

It have change the alternatives of most of the Java related tools.

More comment on this subject can be found on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java) for a similar question. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java) is also related, and an answer link to the same program.