# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter raspberrypi not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I couldn't understand why it doesn't work. Can you write a little explanation

```
    __________________________________________________________
    --------eclipse version-----------
    
    openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Raspbian-3deb10u1)
    OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Raspbian-3deb10u1, mixed mode)
    
    
    
    
    ____________________________________________________________________________
    -------eclipse error log----------------
    
    
    
    !SESSION Mon Jul 06 23:05:19 TRT 2020 ------------------------------------------
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-07-06 23:05:20.022
    !MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
    !STACK
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at o
    
    rg.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    
    
    
    
    ________________________________________________________________________
    -------------eclipse /usr/share/eclipse/configuration/config.ini-------
    
    #This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
    #Wed Feb 21 18:41:43 UTC 2018
    org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
    eclipse.p2.profile=PlatformProfile
    osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
    osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
    equinox.use.ds=true
    eclipse.buildId=debbuild
    osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar@1\:start
    org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.useCairo=true
    org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
    eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
    osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
    osgi.framework.extensions=
    osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
    eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
    eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
    
    
    
    
    ________________________________________________________________________
    ---------eclipse plugins-------------
    
    org.eclipse.ant.core_3.2.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.compare_3.5.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.compare.core_3.5.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.boot_3.1.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.externaltools_1.0.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.filebuffers_3.5.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.3.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.resources_3.8.1.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.2.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.100.dist
    org.eclipse.core.variables_3.2.600.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.cvs_1.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.debug.ui_3.8.1.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf_3.1.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer_5.0.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.identity_3.1.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer_3.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient_4.0.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ssl_1.0.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl_1.0.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ecf.ssl_1.0.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent_1.0.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin_2.0.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox_1.0.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.log_1.2.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console_1.0.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app_1.0.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher_1.0.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation_1.2.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector_1.0.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor_1.0.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.1.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.2.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_2.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher_1.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse_1.1.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ql_2.0.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools_2.0.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse_2.1.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives_1.1.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_2.2.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport_1.0.1.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk_1.0.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler_1.1.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker_1.1.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite_1.0.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.1.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui_1.1.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator_2.0.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.help.appserver_3.1.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.8.2.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.1.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.jsch.core_1.1.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.jsch.ui_1.1.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_3.6.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist
    org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_3.8.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.team.cvs.core_3.3.500.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh2_3.2.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui_3.3.500.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.text_3.5.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.browser_3.4.1.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.console_3.5.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.8.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.externaltools_3.2.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.5.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.8.1.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.0.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.dist
    org.eclipse.ui.navigator_3.5.200.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.net_1.2.101.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.presentations.r21_3.2.201.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.views_3.6.100.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed_3.5.300.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.ui.workbench.compatibility_3.2.101.dist
    org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.8.0.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.update.core_3.2.600.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.update.scheduler_3.2.400.dist.jar
    org.eclipse.update.ui_3.3.0.dist.jar
```

Comment: The JDK and build of Eclipse are both Raspbian packages?

Comment: That appears to be Eclipse 3.8.1 which is now 8 years and 14 releases old. This release is too old to run with Java 11 - Java 8 is probably the last release it will run on.

Answer (score 1):

## Multiple problems

### Class not found

The `ClassNotFoundException` can be because of your usage of JDK11. Maybe Jigsaw Project (modularization) being part of Java 11 is the problem why classes are not found. So THIS problem could be solved by using JDK8. The eclipse version coming with apt is normally very old and not able to handle modularization correctly.

If you have multiple java installations on your Linux system you can toggle between them via:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Fore more details refer to [alternative command description on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java)

Or you change the `eclipse.ini` file and point out your wanted JDK without changing your default java version: [eclipse.ini VM Linux example (Eclipse Wiki)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example)

### Eclipse APT version very old

Unfortunately most Linux distributions provide only very old versions of eclipse "out-of-the-box". I would suggest to download newer packages from
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ - at least for i386 architectures.

Using such extreme old eclipse versions will be extreme slow and you will have not access to newest plugins on eclipse market place, because marketplace solutions describe for which version they are running and most plugins require at least Java 8 and Eclipse Oxygen nowadays.

### 32bit OS support has been dropped

Eclipse project has dropped support for 32bit Windows and Linux [(see Release info for "Photon")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases) - so if your OS is 32 bit...

### SWT native parts not available on ARM per default

The Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT) which is used by eclipse to paint menus, components and all other UI parts is a native library - so it's different for Linux, Windows, Mac...

At the moment on [SWT build platform](https://ci.eclipse.org/releng/view/SWT%20Natives/) only

- mac 64bit (i386)
- gtk linux 64bit (power pc + i386)
- windows 64bit (i386)

are build.

## Quo vadis?

Maybe you can install a 64bit Linux version on your raspberry pi to solve the 32bit problem.

But I am not sure if this will bring up eclipse to start, because the mentioned `SWT` library is not build for ARM architecture.

So as long as t here is no official support or somebody doing a ARM based build for SWT it's difficult to have a running eclipse on your PI. But having Apple going to `ARM` plattform as well, maybe it will happen for linux arm as well in future ?

Here some **additional links**:

- [Compiling Eclipse for Raspberry Pi - Eclipse Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099602/)
- [CI eclipse platform - SWT natives](https://ci.eclipse.org/releng/view/SWT%20Natives/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer
I made the jdk version 8
I have not tried.
I have tried other things before.
I downloaded the 64 bit new version of raspberry pi. I will try