# The jar command cannot be found

Tags: java

Command Prompt gives me this output('jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.) when I enter the command 'jar'. I have installed the Java Development Kit 16 and I have set my JAVA_HOME Variable. java -version works! Why does it not work?

Comment: because `jar` is not a command. You need to use it with `java -jar <name-of-your-jar-file>`

Comment: @Jude Niroshan, `jar` is the command to create jar file. It is provided with the JDK (not JRE).

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your `PATH` environment variable, add:

- Windows : `...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
- Linux : `...:${JAVA_HOME}/bin`

With Linux, you can also have a look to `update-java-alternatives` or `update-alternatives`.
This will create symbolic links to your JDK binaries.
See: [How to use the command update-alternatives --config java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java)