# Swing can't be found

Tags: java, missing-symbols

I have this version of Java installed on a Linux Mint 20.3 Una :

> java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)

Everything works fine except when I tried to import `javax.swing.*`, `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` are well set in my `.bashrc` configuration file.

The installation resides on `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle` if it can be of any helpful information.  I am out of clues, would there be any other file that is supposed to carry important data ? How to get around this ?

My error is that the package is physically on disk but can't be found by the compiler. (I have veriified inside the `src.zip` file)

Here is my piece of `.bashrc`

> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin"

> export JAVA_HOME

> CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/*:~/java/saxon/saxon-he-11.3.jar::~/java/saxon/saxon-he-test-11.3.jar:~/java/saxon/saxon-he-xqj-11.3.jar"

> export CLASSPATH

When compiling with command line `javac name.java` I get error on every call of every swing component looking like this :

> ```
> symbol:   variable BorderLayout
> location: class ETSFrame
> ETSFrame.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
>   c.add(pan2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
> ```

And the first error I get is :

> package javax.swing does not exist (compiler.err.doesnt.exist)

After that point, Java can't resolve anything relative to swing package. The project includes all the base Java packages, like java.desktop ...

Edit 1 :
I made a new installation with OpenJDK 18.0.1, also there was a file that wasn't updated to this new JDK, `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` but even with that updated my problem remains.

> Files edited:
> `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`
> `/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh`
> `/etc/profile`

Comment: How exactly are you compiling? Are you using an IDE? Have you tried writing an utterly simple minimal app? If so, post it.

Comment: I am compiling using command line, but anyway starting from a blank code page, only typing 'import javax.swing.*;' triggers the same kind of error in the editor I use (it's Visual Code but I think is irrelevant since even the command line compiling don't recognize any of the swing components). The program actually works great using another PC... only this time I'm having a hard time with the installation. I took care not to get the headless version of JDK.

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH don't do much for running javac. You need to make sure you're running the correct java version and show the error you get with the import statements. Since those have to work first.

Comment: Not to mention your trying to compile `javac name.java` but the class is "ETSFrame"

Comment: @matt it's more to show no option was used, this didn't solve anything but it is a helluva hint.

Comment: "Visual Code but I think is irrelevant since even the command line compiling don't recognize any of the swing components" This issue comes up, https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/956 which seems related.

Comment: "this didn't solve anything but it is a helluva hint." are you talking about the answer I provided? Can you say what the exact error is when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using java 17 you don't even need to run the compiler directly. Running `java` on a simple class file will invoke the compiler implicitly and then execute the `main` method.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class HW{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new JLabel("hello world"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Save that to a file HW.java and run `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java HW.java`

On a separate note, the JAVA_HOME should point to the directory above bin.

Comment: My problems is the first line, Java tells me this package doesn't exist. But I see it in src.zip, as well as into the referenced libraries of the project.   By any chance do you happen to know how Java is fetching into this zip file ?  Actually clueless, and thanks for the note. (issue remains)

Comment: @jfo420 it doesn't do anything with src.zip. That is the source that was used to build the java you are using. Are you really using the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java`? Quite honestly, I would just go and download a new one and install it locally.

Comment: @jfo420 I don't know if oracle's JDK uses the CLASSPATH environment variable. I'm pretty sure it doesn't, but if it does I think you have it wrong. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/*` that points to the root of the JDK, not where any of the necessary classpath items exist.

Comment: I have no idea, I removed all the previous builds (been trying for one week), then I let Synaptic (provided package manager) do the installation.  The path it installed to seems pretty legit.  But then again, `/bin` holds links to `/etc/alternatives` ... I was thinking everything would hold into one place, am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes. You need to use "update alternatives" and it will let you select the correct java. I would ditch the java_home and classpath from your .bashrc for now since at best it is doing nothing. Ill take a look for the update alternatives and link it. (I'm using a dnf based distro)

Comment: @jfo420 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java that is pretty old, but it seems if you run that command it will tell you which java's are available and you can select the one you want.

Comment: thanks for the link.  For now I installed a new build, openjdk18, I will dig into it tomorrow with fresh head.  There is a lockup somewhere, every build gives me similar result (not recognizing javax.swing).